# Cypress Testing : How to preserve access_token/cookies/sessions?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my application, when I run the application, It redirects to Github Login to access the repository from the account. When the Sign In button is clicked, I get this message.

```
Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.
```

So can anyone tell me what should I do. I tried using Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce() , but it doesn't work.
Also, we get an access_token after successful login.

```
describe('Login Page', () => {
beforeEach(() => {

    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('access_token', 'value for the access_token')
  })
it('successfully logged In', () => {
  cy.get('#login_field').type('username')
  cy.get('#password').type('password')
  cy.get('.btn-block').click()

})
```

})

Comment: Can you explain how you are using the github login. Are you using Oauth. What happens when in your web page you click on signin (not using cypress). Normally.

Comment: No, we are not using Oauth for login. When Sign In is clicked we get an access token on successful login.

Comment: Hey @chandan_kr_jha, actually we initiate the OAuth chain with Github and  Returns Account name and token in JSON, Please ignore the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Cypress Social Media Logins][1]. I think you are using Github Oauth to login and access.

You have to login using the plugin GitHubSocialLogin. Save the cookie that you get in the localStorage.

You will have to explore further on these lines to suit your particular use case.
[1]: https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins

Comment: Thank you @chandan_kr_jha, I'll try this.